# App Inventor linking one to another

Tags: app-inventor

In **App Inventor**, how do I link one `Textbox.txt` on one screen to another `Textbox.txt` on another screen?

I would like to have a `textbox.text` on a say screen3 using the values in the other two...

Comment: [How to pass values from one screen to another screen](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/w7PAggKauz8/aa2YHe5cTKIJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tinyDB to share the text from multiple screens.
A few tips on how to do this:
Use the tinyDB store function on the screens you are getting text then use the get function on the screen you want the info to show up and make sure you remember what tags you put for the store function blocks and that they are different.
If you have any questions, feel free to comment!

Screen1
[image]

Screen2
[image]

Screen3[image]

Comment: the join block in Screen1 does not make sense, does it?

Comment: it does because he wants everything on one screen
it worked for me

Comment: `join "Screen2" "Screen3"` is the same as `"Screen2Screen3"`